# conditional probablity to nullify the result

Tags: probability

If two player playing a game with each other where one flip a coin and if it comes up heads he gives another X dollars and if it comes up tails she gives you Y dollars. The probability that the coin is heads is p (some number between 0 and 1.) What has to be true about X and Y to make so that both of your expected total earnings is 0.

I really dont understand the question. Any explanations?

**Update**

```
E(W) = E(user1) + E(user2)
0 = -a (1-(-a)) + a (1-a)
0 = -a -a^2 + a - a^2
0 = a^2
a = 0
```

but options are :

```
X=Y
p/(1−p)=X/Y
p/(1−p)=Y/X
p=X/Y
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Outline:** I prefer to use $a$ dollars and $b$ dollars. Let random variable $W$ be the tosser's income from a toss. Then $W=-a$ with probability $p$, and $W=b$ with probability $1-p$.

Calculate $E(W)$, set it equal to $0$, and come to a conclusion about the relationship between $a$ and $b$.

Comment: @Nicolas: can you please explain why `W = -a` ?

Comment: If the coin lands head he **gives** the other $a$ dollars, so his "gain" is negative. A loss of $a$ dollars is a "gain" of $-a$ dollars. We could handle the problem differently, using $ap=b(1-p)$. This yields exactly the same result. But for the future it is good to get accustomed to a random variable taking on possibly negative values.

Comment: @Nicolas: thanks a lot, can you please see my udpate?

Comment: You should get (in my notation) $(-a)p+(b)(1-p)=0$, which gives $ap=b(1-p)$, so $\frac{p}{1-p}=\frac{b}{a}$. In the notation of the problem, that's the third of the four options. I will not be able to answer any more questions until tomorrow, it is very late here!